# I cannot make a jquery function simply due to arguments error undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function showBox (event, element)
{
 event.preventDefault();
 element.hide();
 alert(element.next("p").text();
}
```

Then here I have my event binding:

```
var elm = $(selector);

$(elm).on("click", function(event, elm){
    showBox(event, element);
});
```

But it does not works and console errors that element is undefined. (referring to the function's line three)

I could use anonymous functions, but I have to use this login in several places so it seems odd to have the same code repeated everywhere. What is my probelm? thanks

Comment: You don't need to pass in the element as an argument. You can get it from `event.target`

Comment: @xbonez `event.target` can lead to a lot of problems when events bubble to parents with handlers.

Comment: To the OP, in the second code block your variable is named `elm` but you try to pass it to `showBox` as `element`. This is a simple typo/error, thus my vote to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it

```
$(selector).on("click", showBox);

function showBox (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    alert( $(this).next("p").text() );
}
```